# Storing ArrayList<Integer> as key in TreeMap Java

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, treemap

I am storing an arrayList as my keys in a TreeMap but I am getting this exception

**java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable**

I copy the content of array to ArrayList and try to store that arrayList as my keys in the Map
My Code is :

```
TreeMap< ArrayList<Integer> , Integer > bandsMap = new TreeMap< ArrayList<Integer> , Integer >(); 
ArrayList< Integer > erfcn = new ArrayList< Integer >();

for (int index = 0; index < frequencies.length; index++)   
    erfcn.add(frequencies[index]);

    bandsMap.put( erfcn , band_number);

 for (Integer value : bandsMap.values()) {
    System.out.println("Value = " + value + "\n");
 }
```

Any Idea ? 
Thanks

Comment: `java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable`.
`List` doesn't extends `Comparable`, then there are not defined comparing operation through `compareTo(T o)` method on it. You can't use as map key.

Comment: `TreeMap` compares keys before adding them. How do you think it's going to compare two instances of `ArrayList`? What is the criteria that determines that a list is smaller/bigger/equal to another?

Comment: Do you want to construct the building?

Comment: Do you *really* need a `List<Integer>` for the keys? Can you think of a possible workaround?

Comment: I can think of MultiMaps but for that I have to use google guava library which I dont want to use. I have keys which are same and no collection in java support saving duplicate keys with different values

Comment: A Multimap stores collections of values. Collections of keys is not a normal thing to do - you really should rethink your design.

Comment: Keys in a Map should be immutable (like e.g. Strings), so Lists would be a poor choice even if you could use them as keys.

Comment: helpermethod what should I use if my keys have duplicates

Answer (score 5):

A tree map maintains its keys in sorted order. The `ArrayList` class does not define any ordering, so it cannot be used as a key directly. You can supply an external comparator to impose an order though, but you must define an ordering that makes sense to you:

```
TreeMap<ArrayList<Integer>, Integer> bandsMap = new TreeMap<>(
    new Comparator<ArrayList<Integer>>() {
        public int compare(ArrayList<Integer> lst1, ArrayList<Integer> lst2) {
            // return 1 if lst1 > lst2, 0 if equal, -1 if lst1 < lst2
        }
    });
```

Alternatively, if you don't have to maintain the keys in any particular order, use a `HashMap` instead.

Answer (score 2):

[ArrayLists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) don't implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), so you need to use an unsorted map, like [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), or tell the [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) how to sort your `ArrayLists` by using [this constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap%28java.util.Comparator%29).

Answer (score 1):

The error itself indicates the problem. **ArrayList class does not implement java.lang.Comparable interface** and the [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is expecting the key to implement comparable interface. Hence it is causing the exception.

Refer [ArrayList documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

As we cannot go modify ArrayList, you can use external [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to make ArrayList work as a key to the TreeMap. You just need to override compare() method in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare two lists, you have to either change list to some other structure, or make your own list using Comparable interface. Good solution is also to wrap up list in new class which implements Comparable and implement just this method from interface.

Check out this

```
public class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit>{
     public int compareTo(Fruit compareFruit) {
    //your code here 
     }  
}
```

and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) link. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** want to use ArrayList as key in TreeMap, then you need to write [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for it and pass is [using constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap%28java.util.Comparator%29)

Using List as key in Tree is not a good idea, please review your design.

Answer (score 0):

Given what the other answers have said about `List`s not implementing Comparable, you could create your own class to act as TreeMap keys, extending ArrayList and implementing Comparable:

```
class KeyList extends ArrayList<Integer> implements Comparable<ArrayList<Integer>> {

  public int compareTo(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    //decide how to compare ArrayLists, then implement it here 
    return 0;
  }

}
```

Then you can create your TreeMap:

```
new TreeMap<KeyList, Integer>();
```